# Why does my Azure Build break when I add a WPF 4.72 app to my solution?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Environment:
Web API .Net Core 3.1
WPF 4.72
Wix 3.1.2
Visual Studio 2019 Pro ed.

The following is my build script for my Wix installer and my Web API project only:

```
trigger:
- master

pool: 'TakeKidsToPool'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Publish API
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: false
    arguments: /p:PublishProfile=FolderProfile -c $(buildConfiguration)
    zipAfterPublish: false
    modifyOutputPath: false

- task: MSBuild@1
  displayName: Create API msi
  inputs:
    solution: SetupProject1/*.wixproj
    msbuildArchitecture: x64
    configuration: $(buildConfiguration)
```

When I add a WPF project to the solution and not even change the build script it fails on the publish part which has nothing to do with the WPF project. I don't understand.

```
  Determining projects to restore...
  Restored C:\agent2\_work\10\s\WebApplication1\WebApplication1.csproj (in 891 ms).
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.402\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1177,5): error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks [C:\agent2\_work\10\s\WpfApp1\WpfApp1.csproj]
  WebApplication1 -> C:\agent2\_work\10\s\WebApplication1\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\win-x64\WebApplication1.dll
  WebApplication1 -> C:\agent2\_work\10\s\WebApplication1\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\win-x64\publish\
##[error]Error: The process 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1
##[error]Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects : 
##[section]Finishing: Publish API
```

Here's the publish profile that is a parameter in the build script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121. 
-->
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>False</DeleteExistingFiles>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <PublishProvider>FileSystem</PublishProvider>
    <PublishUrl>bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\publish\</PublishUrl>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <PublishSingleFile>True</PublishSingleFile>
    <ProjectGuid>5c246494-0b84-4e8b-943b-e13381b8fb83</ProjectGuid>
    <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

If we use self-hosted agent, we need to configure the environment on the local machine.  According to the error message, It seems that your agent machine do not have the .NETFramework 4.7.2, we should Install the [.NET Framework 4.7.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/guide-for-developers) and restart the agent.

Comment: The frameworks I need are definitely installed on the build server. I think I found the issue so I'll add as an answer.

Comment: Hi @Rod, if you do not add the project path, it will publish all projects, the issue is publish WPF project instead of web app. In addition, you could accept your answer, In this case, others could directly find the useful solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I had to add some specificity to publish command with the projects argument. I put the Web API project path here and the build now works. I guess it was trying to publish both the Web API and WPF projects.

Anymore insights?

[image]